# jQuery load and SEO

Tags: jquery, ajax, seo

I'm developing a web app which use jQuery's ajax load function to load content from an XML file. Is it true that web crawlers don't execute JavaScript when crawling, and if so, how can I combat this?

Comment: do you use JSON ? (I can't deny myself on that name)

Answer (score 1):

Yes crawlers knows nothing about javascript, for SEO it is better to load important information of your web pages when the page loads in normal way.
for combat with previous problem you can create a hidden link, or a link with no content  referring to the web service you are calling on the startup, cause web crawlers visit links but I don't recommend this method

Answer (score 0):

What about this - http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html ?